# Can't add more code to loop() when use server.handleClient

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

Here's my code

```
void loop() {
  if (analogRead(A0) > 500)
  {
    statuss = true ;
  }
  if (statuss)
  {
    digitalWrite(D7, HIGH);
    if (millis() - lasttime > 500)
    {
      digitalWrite(D8, etat);
      digitalWrite(D6, etat);
      etat = !etat;
      lasttime = millis();
    }
  }
  server.handleClient();
}
```

When I use only `server.handleClient` everything works fine but when I add any type of code to the `loop()` function the server goes down and I can't see the ESP8266 access point.

Comment: what is `any type of code` ?  .... also,  you have not asked a question.

Comment: `when i use only server.handleClient` .... your code has other commands ... your statement does not make sense

Comment: that's the problem with close reason "Unclear what you are asking". for me it is totally clear about what this question is. and I am glad it is not closed yet

Comment: @Juraj, i am trying to understand .... if, for example, the OP adds a serial.print() statement to the loop(), then the server goes down ..... how is that clear to you? .... have you had similar experience?

Comment: @jsotola, read my answer

Comment: that is a specific command, not "any type of code" .... maybe the translation from OP's language is the blame, but it is still unclear what is being asked

Comment: @gre_gor, sempaiscuba, VE7JRO, MatsK, per123, you closed this question without evaluating/testing. the Question says: "if I run this code the esp8266 disappears from the WiFi network". and it is true. the question is "why?, what should I change?"

Comment: @jsotola, yes, asker didn't do the troubleshooting to reduce the code to minimum. he deserves the downvotes

Comment: Voting to re-open and +1 for your answer Juraj.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is analogRead. The esp8266 uses the ADC to evaluate the strength of the WiFi signal. Hard use of analogRead disturbs it and the signal goes down. Use millis() to time analogRead.

```
unsigned int tempSensRead() {

  const unsigned long MEASURE_INTERVAL = 2L * 1000 * 60; // 2 minutes
  static unsigned long lastMeasureMillis;
  static unsigned int lastValue;

  if (millis() - lastMeasureMillis > MEASURE_INTERVAL) {
    lastMeasureMillis = millis();
    lastValue = analogRead(A0);
  }
  return lastValue;
}
```

Comment: @fakherhabib, some feedback please

Comment: Nice answer. Do you know any sources which confirm the statement "esp8266 uses the ADC to evaluate the strength of the WiFi signal"? I couldn't find this on the [datasheet](https://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf)

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#analog-input

Comment: Excellent resource, thanks.